# Can we use robocopy to copy files instead of folders

Tags: windows, teamcity, msdeploy, robocopy

I need to copy a particular file from one location to another., Is it possible to use robocopy to do same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst Robocopy can be persuaded to copy a single file it is much simpler to use copy or xcopy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, either wrap it in an an exec or use the Robocopy that is wrapped as part of the msbuild extension pack see:http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.3.0/index.html

You want to use the MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.RoboCopy task.
Makes copying much quicker.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to figure this problem out. I finally found my own solution and maybe it will help.

I noticed that the syntax used to select the entire directory could be used to select a single file.

```
ROBOCOPY "*" "Directory source" "Directory Output unc path or non"
```

The above code will copy everything from the directory source folder to the directory output path.

Let's say you only wanted to copy 1 file from the directory source named "test.txt"

In order to do that use the following code:

```
ROBOCOPY "*test.txt" "Directory source" "Directory Output unc path or non"
```

Thats about it. It works really well and will only copy the file name you want.

Alternatively you can use

```
ROBOCOPY "*.txt" "Directory source" "Directory Output unc path or non"
```

to copy out all text documents from the directory source.
Similarly this will also work with any .ext

.zip .exe .txt .pdf etc..

I signed up to answer this question with a better method. Let me know if I succeeded.